# Which game is this animation of a guy with a green shirt, backpack, and blue pants from?

Tags: game-identification

I don't really know if it's from a game, but it surely looks like:

[image: unknown]

This animation is used as avatar in several different forums over the internet.

Comment: +1 for being the first Game Identification I've seen in ages with an actual artifact.

Comment: If you dump this image into Google image search (in the Chrome browser you can just right click "Search Google for this image", Google also answers this question correctly :-)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

That's the titular Boy, from [A Boy and His Blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Boy_and_His_Blob:_Trouble_on_Blobolonia), on the NES.

Here he is alongside his Blob, I believe in the process of tossing the Blob a jellybean:

[image: The Boy, also his Blob]

[Animated GIF version of the toss on tumblr, for those interested](http://brotherbrain.tumblr.com/post/19593961534/blob-loves-jelly-beans-bybrother-brain-a-boy)

Comment: Hot holy crap, an ITG that both had a salient A/V artifact and got answered. It's a christmas miracle!

Comment: when things go as planned its poetic.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh: Currently all of our [(valid) ITG questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) have been answered.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft In my defense, I have not been on Arqade for a long time (since about the time the ITG debate was raging) and hadn't seen a valid one be answered.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh it's February

Comment: Hahaha that game was soooo wierd. I remeber I thought the city in the background looked quite photorealistic at the time thou :)